# Python - Writing to a text file using functions?

Tags: python, file-io, function

i wrote a simple function to write into a text file. like this,

```
def write_func(var):
        var = str(var)
        myfile.write(var)
a= 5
b= 5
c= a + b
write_func(c)
```

this will write the output to a desired file.
now, i want the output in another format. say,

```
write_func("Output is :"+c)
```

so that the output will have a meaningful name in the file. how do i do it?
and why is that i cant write an integer to a file? i do, *int = str(int)* before writing to a file?

Answer (score 3):

You can't add/concatenate a string and integer directly.

If you do anything more complicated than `"string :"+str(number)`, I would strongly recommend using [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
write_func('Output is: %i' % (c))
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple, you do:

```
write_func('Output is' + str(c))
```

You have to convert `c` to a string before you can concatenate it with another string. Then you can also take off the:

```
var = str(var)
```

From your function.

---

> why is that i cant write an integer to
>   a file? i do, int = str(int) before
>   writing to a file?

You *can* write binary data to a file, but byte representations of numbers aren't really human readable. -2 for example is `0xfffffffe` in a 2's complement 32-bit integer. It's even worse when the number is a `float`: 2.1 is `0x40066666`.

If you plan on having a human-readable file, you need to human-readable characters on them. In an ASCII file '0.5' isn't a number (at least not as a computer understands numbers), but instead the characters `'0', '.' and '5'`. And that's why you need convert your numbers to strings.

Comment: I do not agree with human readability argument. In fact the `str` that `write` accepts is a byte string. It can be a 4-byte representation of the (short) int just as well (you can obtain it using `struct` module).

Comment: @Constantin OK, do you prefer `0x3F000000` or 0.5?

Comment: I think the argument should go: Why can't you write an integer to a file?  Because `write` takes a series of bytes.  If you want binary data, then give it binary data.  If you want readable/ASCII/unicode (as OP wants), then give it printable bytes.  Files contain whatever you specify. :P

Comment: @NullUserException, sometimes i prefer 0x3F000000. Still, you give the wrong reason to the design decision behind the fact that `file.write` in Python accepts byte strings, but not ints or other arbitrary objects. It has nothing to do with readability of resulting file.

Comment: Ugh I can't get the wording right. Feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: @NullUserException: Ok, the *real* reason is because writing a number, or even integer to a file is totally ambiguous.  Files could go anywhere, to be read by anything.  It could be stored as a `uint8`, a `uint16`, a `uint32`, a `uint64`, a `Bignum` (Python long), or maybe even a `Decimal`, `float` or `double` (`quad`?).  If you want something Python specific, `pickle` is the tool to use

Answer (score 2):

Python is a [*strongly typed*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_typed_programming_language) language. This means, among other things, that you cannot concatenate a string and an integer. Therefore you'll have to convert the integer to string before concatenating. This can be done using a format string (as Nick T [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499961/python-writing-to-a-text-file-using-functions/3499994#3499994)) or passing the integer to the built in `str` function (as NullUserException [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499961/python-writing-to-a-text-file-using-functions/3499971#3499971)).

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.write

> file.write(str)
>
> Write a string to the file. There is no return value. Due to buffering,
> the string may not actually show up in
> the file until the flush() or close()
> method is called.

Note how documentation specifies that `write`'s argument must be a string.

So you should create a string yourself before passing it to `file.write()`.